# How was the first working version of Google written?

Tags: programming

Which language and/or server software did Google use for its initial version?

Comment: @{Downvoters}: Care to explain why you downvoted? It's better to explain so the problems can be remedied if possible.

Answer (score 8):

When Google was just a research project at Stanford headed up by Larry Page, it was known as **BackRub**. This name alluded to the fact that the PageRank algorithm being developed relied on traversing backlinks to rank each indexed search result by something related to its popularity.

The original BackRub can still be viewed via the WayBack Machine. This [early version from 1998](http://web.archive.org/web/19980207005959/http://backrub.stanford.edu:80/backrub.html) indicates that the project was implemented in Java and Python and ran on Sun Ultra servers as well as Linux machines on Intel Pentiums hardware.

Comment: `Total content downloaded: 207.022 gigabytes` So in other words the entire contents of "Google" at that point would fit on the MicroSD card currently mounted in my Android phone...